# Rails - Devise : Check if user can sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise to deal with Session.

I need to check if a user is validate by admin before sign in.

I added a boolean field in my model 'is_validated'.

How can I check this field before sign_in a user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `active_for_authentication?` function of devise. Basically you place your extra condition in that method and only if that method is true one can log in.

You can find more details here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the active_for_authentication? method in your model

Like this .......

```
class Your_model

  def active_for_authentication?
    super && is_validated?
  end

end
```

This returns true if user is validated.